# Yandex maps api: удалить значки магазинов, ТЦ и т.п

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

При создании карты выводятся значки магазинов, ТЦ и т.п. Так вот:

1. Можно ли их с карты удалить?
2. Или с помощью yandex maps api получить информацию о них?

[![описание][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnIE7.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это организации, их нельзя отключить, они нарисованы в самих тайлах, для поиска информации по организациям вам возможно поможет [этот API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/concepts/response_structure_business-docpage/).